# Request.form doesn't work for all fields

Tags: asp.net

This is my form code.

```
response.write("<form action='newRequest.asp' method='post' id='newRequest' data-ajax='false' name='newRequest'>")
'Three column table
response.write("<table border=0><tr>")
response.write("<td>")
response.write("Date received: <input type='text' name='dReceived' value='" & Date & "' Disabled>")
response.write("<input name='doRequest' type=hidden value='yes'/>")
response.write("</td>")
response.write("<td>")
response.write("Time received: <input type='text' name='tReceived' value='" & Time & "' disabled>")
response.write("</td>")
response.write("<td valign=middle align=center rowspan=2 class='tagBottom'>")
response.write("<div>Work Order No:")
response.write("<h1 class='workOrder'>" & wOrder & "</h1><div>")
response.write("<input type='hidden' value='" & wOrder & "' name='wOrder' class='tagNo'>")
response.write("</td>")
response.write("</tr>")
response.write("<tr>")
response.write("<td>")

    Set RS2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    RS2.activeConnection = Conn
    RS2.locktype  = adLockOptimistic
    RS2.cursorlocation = adUseClient
    sql = "SELECT * "
    sql = sql & "FROM tblEmployees "
    sql = sql & "Order by EmployeeName"
    RS2.Open sql
    response.write("Received by:")
    response.write("<select name='officerNum'>")
    response.write("<option value='" & esUserID & "' selected>" & esUserID & "</option>")
        Do While not RS2.EOF
            response.write("<option value='" & titleCase(RS2("EmployeeId")) & "'>" & titleCase(RS2("EmployeeName")) & "</option>")
            RS2.MoveNext            
        loop
    RS2.Close
    response.write("</select>") 
response.write("</td>")
response.write("<td>")
response.write("</td>") 
response.write("</tr>")
response.write("<tr>")  
response.write("<td>")
    response.write("First Name: <input type='text' name='fName' id='fName'>")
response.write("</td>") 
response.write("<td>")
    response.write("Last Name: <input type='text' name='lName'>")
response.write("</td>")
response.write("<td>")
            response.write("Home Phone: <input type='text' name='hPhone'>")         
response.write("</td>") 
response.write("</tr>") 
response.write("<tr>")  
response.write("<td>")
    response.write("Address: <input type='text' name='address' id='sAddress'>")
response.write("</td>") 
response.write("<td align=center valign=middle class=button>")
    response.write("<a href='#' onclick='openGoogle();' data-theme='e' type=button class='ui-btn-right'>Map It</a>")
response.write("</td>") 
response.write("<td>")
    response.write("Cell Phone: <input type='text' name='cPhone'>")         
response.write("</td>") 
response.write("</tr>")
response.write("<tr>")  
response.write("<td>")

    Set RS3 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    RS3.activeConnection = Conn
    RS3.locktype  = adLockOptimistic
    RS3.cursorlocation = adUseClient
    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT CityID, CityNameZip "
    sql = sql & "FROM tblCityList "
    sql = sql & "Order by CityNameZip Asc"
    RS3.Open sql
    response.write("City:")
    response.write("<select name='city' id='city'>")
        response.write("<option value='NULL'>Select City</option>")
        Do While not RS3.EOF
            response.write("<option value='" & titleCase(RS3("CityID")) & "'>" & titleCase(RS3("CityNameZip")) & "</option>")
            RS3.MoveNext            
        loop
    RS3.Close
    response.write("</select>")
response.write("</td>") 
response.write("<td align=center valign=bottom>")
    response.write("State:<h3>SC</h3><input type='hidden' value='SC' name='state'>")
response.write("</td>")         
response.write("<td>")
    response.write("Work Phone: <input type='text' name='wPhone'>") 
response.write("</td>")
response.write("<tr>")
response.write("<td class=button colspan=3>")
response.write("<div data-role='controlgroup' data-type='horizontal' data-mini='false'>")
    response.write("<a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='grid' data-theme='e'>Kennel Card</a>")
    response.write("<a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='check' data-theme='e'>Turnaround and Print</a>")
    response.write("<a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='check' data-theme='e'>Animal in Trap</a>")
    response.write("</div>")
response.write("</td>") 
response.write("</tr>") 

response.write("<tr>")
response.write("<td colspan=3>")
    response.write("<a href='newRequest.asp?action=Print' data-theme='e' type=button>Print</a>")        
response.write("</td>")             
response.write("</tr>")     
response.write("<tr>")
response.write("<td colspan=3>")
    response.write("<hr>")  
response.write("</td>")             
response.write("</tr>") 
response.write("<tr>")
response.write("<td>")
    Set RS4 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    RS4.activeConnection = Conn
    RS4.locktype  = adLockOptimistic
    RS4.cursorlocation = adUseClient
    sql = "SELECT * "
    sql = sql & "FROM tblEmployees "
    sql = sql & "Order by EmployeeName"
    RS4.Open sql
    response.write("Assigned To:")
    response.write("<select name='assignedOfficer' id='assignedOfficer'>")
    response.write("<option value='NULL' selected>Select Officer</option>")
        Do While not RS4.EOF
            response.write("<option value='" & titleCase(RS4("EmployeeId")) & "'>" & titleCase(RS4("EmployeeName")) & "</option>")
            RS4.MoveNext            
        loop
    RS4.Close
    response.write("</select>")     
response.write("</td>")
response.write("<td>")
response.write("</td>")
response.write("<td rowspan=4 valign=top class='textArea'>")
    response.write("Additional Info:")
    response.write("<textarea name='addInfo' class='addInfo'>Input any additional info here.</textarea>")   
response.write("</td>")                     
response.write("</tr>") 

response.write("<tr>")
response.write("<td>")
    Set RS5 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    RS5.activeConnection = Conn
    RS5.locktype  = adLockOptimistic
    RS5.cursorlocation = adUseClient
    sql = "SELECT * "
    sql = sql & "FROM tblAnimalList "
    sql = sql & "Order by AnimalTypeID"
    RS5.Open sql
    response.write("Animal Type:")
    response.write("<select name='animalType' id='animalType'>")
    response.write("<option value='NULL' selected>Select Animal</option>")
        Do While not RS5.EOF
            response.write("<option value='" & titleCase(RS5("AnimalTypeID")) & "'>" & titleCase(RS5("AnimalSpecies")) & "</option>")
            RS5.MoveNext            
        loop
    RS5.Close
    response.write("</select>")     
response.write("</td>")
response.write("<td align=center>")
        response.write("Trap #<br>")
        response.write("<input type='text' value='' name='trapNum'>")
response.write("</td>") 
response.write("</tr>")

response.write("<tr>")
response.write("<td>")
    Set RS6 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    RS6.activeConnection = Conn
    RS6.locktype  = adLockOptimistic
    RS6.cursorlocation = adUseClient
    sql = "SELECT * "
    sql = sql & "FROM tblAnimalStatus "
    sql = sql & "Order by AnimalStatusID"
    RS6.Open sql
    response.write("Status:")
    response.write("<select name='aStatus' id='aStatus'>")
    response.write("<option value='' selected>Select Status</option>")
        Do While not RS6.EOF
            response.write("<option value='" & titleCase(RS6("AnimalStatusID")) & "'>" & titleCase(RS6("AnimalStatus")) & "</option>")
            RS6.MoveNext            
        loop
    RS6.Close
    response.write("</select>")     
response.write("</td>")
response.write("</tr>")

response.write("<tr>")
response.write("<td colspan=2>")
    Set RS7 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    RS7.activeConnection = Conn
    RS7.locktype  = adLockOptimistic
    RS7.cursorlocation = adUseClient
    sql = "SELECT * "
    sql = sql & "FROM tblRequest "
    sql = sql & "Order by RequestID"
    RS7.Open sql
    response.write("Services Requested:")
    response.write("<select name='services' id='services'>")
    response.write("<option value='' selected>Services Requested</option>")
        Do While not RS7.EOF
            response.write("<option value='" & titleCase(RS7("RequestID")) & "'>" & titleCase(RS7("ServiceRequested")) & "</option>")
            RS7.MoveNext            
        loop
    RS7.Close
    response.write("</select>")     
response.write("</td>")
response.write("</tr>")

response.write("<tr>")
response.write("<td colspan=3>")
response.write("<hr>")
response.write("</td>")
response.write("</tr>")

response.write("<tr>")
response.write("<td>")
    response.write("<label for=slider2>Close Call</label><br>")
    response.write("<select name='closeCall' id='closeCall' data-role='slider' onChange=""setDate(this.value);""><option value='False' selected>No</option><option value='True'>Yes</option>")
response.write("</td>")
response.write("<td colspan=2>")
    response.write("<div class='block'><label>Date and Time Call Closed:</label><br><input type='text' value='' name='dtCloseCall' id='dtCloseCall' disabled/></div>")
    response.write("<input type=hidden id=realCloseDate name=realCloseDate>")
response.write("</td>")
response.write("</tr>")

response.write("<tr>")
response.write("<td colspan=3>")
    response.write("<textarea name='notes' class='addInfo' rows='10' cols='50'>Notes</textarea>")
response.write("</td>")
response.write("</tr>")


response.write("</table>")
'response.write("<input type='submit' class='sub-btn' id='subButton' data-transition='slide' name='Selection' value='Save'>")& vbcrlf   
response.write("<div data-role='footer' data-position='fixed'>")
response.write("<h4>Florence County - Officer: " & esUserID & "</h4>")
response.write("<a href='newRequest.asp' data-theme='e' class='ui-btn-right' onclick=""checkToSave();document.getElementById('newRequest').submit();"">Save</a>")
response.write("</div>")
response.write("</div>")
response.write("</form>")
```

When I iterate through the form elements using this:

```
for each f in request.form()
  response.write("<p>" & f & " = " & request.form(f) &"</p>")
next
```

It returns all the elements except for some of the "Select" objects. For instance it returns the "City" value, but not the assignedOfficer, animalType, aStatus, or services items. All the standard Input and Textarea fields work fine.

I get this from the debug code:

```
doRequest = yes

state = stateName

realCloseDate =

wOrder = 22303

address = some address

officerNum = 42

lName = lastName

city = 1

fName = firstName

hPhone = 5555555555

cPhone = 5555555555

addInfo = Input any additional info here.

notes = Notes

wPhone = 5555555555

trapNum =

closeCall = False
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the reason for the behavior. In my javascript validation of the select tag data I set the value of the select to 0 if the closed state of the workorder was false. Don't know what I was thinking when I did that, except that the database wasn't accepting null values and I was giving it a value. Unfortuantely setting the Select to 0 must have disabled the object instead of set a value.